# Is there a way to get the extension's settings (defined in package.json) at runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a Visual Studio Code extension, is there a way to get the extension's settings (defined in package.json) at runtime?  There are a few values (like displayName) that I'd like to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Visual Studio Code extension is written in JavaScript and no different from a standard Node script, so generally speaking you can use `fs.readFile` to read the extension manifest and `JSON.parse` to read its values.

Depending on your use-case there might be simpler options.

### require()

To read your own extension's `package.json`, you could simply use `require()`

**Example:**

```
// lib/extension.js
const meta = require('../package.json')
```

### import

The same as above is possible with an `import`, at least when using TypeScript.

**Example**:

```
// src/extension.ts
import * as meta from '../package.json'
```

Make sure to add a type declarations for JSON files

```
// src/index.d.ts
declare module '*.json' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

### Node dependency

Last but not least, you can read *any* extension's `package.json` programmatically. Using a Node packages such as [vscode-read-manifest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vscode-read-manifest), [read-pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-pkg) (or [read-pkg-up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-pkg-up)) make it easy.

**Example:**

```
const readManifest = require('vscode-read-manifest');

// Async
(async () => {
    let manifest = await readManifest('ms-python.python');
})();

// Sync
let manifest = readManifest.sync('ms-python.python');
```

Comment: Thanks @idleberg. I was hoping for an API to get this, but reading the file directly will work.

Comment: Thanks @idleberg.  I went w/just using fs and fs.readFileSync:  
  
    `let packageJson: string = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../package.json"), "utf8");  `  
    `let projectPackage: gist.IPackage = JSON.parse(packageJson);  `  

(I'm using the TS description for a package from (https://gist.github.com/iainreid820/5c1cc527fe6b5b7dba41fec7fe54bf6e)
If I need to do anything more complex, I'll look into read-pkg.  
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access `package.json` content from the `vscode.ExtensionContext`:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(ctx: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const id = ctx.extension.id;
    const version = ctx.extension.packageJSON.version;
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`${id} ${version}`);
}
```